# How to return a list of user-defined struct in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ico

I want to return a list of user-defined struct

```
function sortByEtherValues (string category) public view returns (JobStruct[]) {
...
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Failed to decode output: Error: Unsupported or invalid type: tuple

Answer (score 1):

Solidity supports [returning multiple values](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#returning-multiple-values):

```
struct JobStruct {
  uint a;
  uint b;
  uint c;
}

function sortByEtherValues (string category) public view returns (uint, uint, uint) {
  JobStruct memory js = JobStruct(1, 2, 3);
  return (js.a, js.b, js.c);
}
```

It'll be a little dirty to return an array of structs by decomposing your `struct` elements. If you can, you should try to return just a single `JobStruct` by getting the number of elements by `category` in a separate function, then adding the index to `sortByEtherValues`.